# unable to generate a token for user in new org using balance transfer use case in hyperledger fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, user-enrollment

I am using hyperleger fabric-sample network. I changed the configuration bit, added a new org into it, I am using balance transfer use case and when I am trying to enrol user I am getting the following error:

Request I sent:

```
curl -s -X POST http://localhost:4000/users -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'username=Jim&orgName=Org3'
```

Error I am getting:

````
{"success":false,"message":"failed Error: Common connection profile is missing this client's organization and mspid"}```

log of my node app:

[2019-10-19 13:24:57.682] [DEBUG] SampleWebApp -  ------>>>>>> new request for /users
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.682] [DEBUG] SampleWebApp - End point : /users
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.682] [DEBUG] SampleWebApp - User name : Jim
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.682] [DEBUG] SampleWebApp - Org name  : Org3
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.683] [DEBUG] Helper - getClientForOrg - ****** START Org3 undefined
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.690] [DEBUG] Helper - [NetworkConfig101.js]: constructor, network_config: {"name":"balance-transfer","x-type":"hlfv1","description":"Balance Transfer Network","version":"1.0","channels":{"mychannel":{"orderers":["orderer.example.com"],"peers":{"peer0.org1.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":true,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":true},"peer1.org1.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":false,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":false},"peer2.org1.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":false,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":false},"peer0.org2.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":true,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":true},"peer1.org2.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":false,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":false},"peer2.org2.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":false,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":false},"peer0.org3.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":true,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":true},"peer1.org3.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":false,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":false},"peer2.org3.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":false,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":false},"peer0.org4.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":true,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":true},"peer1.org4.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":false,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":false},"peer2.org4.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":false,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":false},"peer0.org5.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":true,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":true},"peer1.org5.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":false,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":false},"peer2.org5.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":false,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":false},"peer0.org6.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":true,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":true},"peer1.org6.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":false,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":false},"peer2.org6.example.com":{"endorsingPeer":false,"chaincodeQuery":true,"ledgerQuery":true,"eventSource":false}},"chaincodes":["mycc:v0"]}},"organizations":{"Org1":{"mspid":"Org1MSP","peers":["peer0.org1.example.com","peer1.org1.example.com","peer2.org1.example.com"],"certificateAuthorities":["ca-org1"],"adminPrivateKey":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/c4179a68cc1f71e51919f7541be599ec0d2924426b4e64159fbf3fcaec419463_sk"},"signedCert":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem"}},"Org2":{"mspid":"Org2MSP","peers":["peer0.org2.example.com","peer1.org2.example.com","peer2.org2.example.com"],"certificateAuthorities":["ca-org2"],"adminPrivateKey":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/keystore/eff846bd66dc8801f1979fa40a4fe238f5b6a5e0eda2ae052d3383606d508485_sk"},"signedCert":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem"}},"Org3":{"mspid":"Org3MSP","peers":["peer0.org3.example.com","peer1.org3.example.com","peer2.org3.example.com"],"certificateAuthorities":["ca-org3"],"adminPrivateKey":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/users/Admin@org3.example.com/msp/keystore/9f40b162c33476c40b521d0e12f840429dbefcfcec097b6aa256b398f0910dea_sk"},"signedCert":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/users/Admin@org3.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org3.example.com-cert.pem"}},"Org4":{"mspid":"Org4MSP","peers":["peer0.org4.example.com","peer1.org4.example.com","peer2.org4.example.com"],"certificateAuthorities":["ca-org4"],"adminPrivateKey":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/users/Admin@org4.example.com/msp/keystore/69b52012f2b133b1564dd22248ca7ca47895a433a6e23828db17ed9abb306e6c_sk"},"signedCert":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/users/Admin@org4.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org4.example.com-cert.pem"}},"Org5":{"mspid":"Org5MSP","peers":["peer0.org5.example.com","peer1.org5.example.com","peer2.org5.example.com"],"certificateAuthorities":["ca-org5"],"adminPrivateKey":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org5.example.com/users/Admin@org5.example.com/msp/keystore/53237c803abb8d84a06bb6554289f0a8e1512de26c9778d84d26c8415c7ba242_sk"},"signedCert":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org5.example.com/users/Admin@org5.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org5.example.com-cert.pem"}},"Org6":{"mspid":"Org6MSP","peers":["peer0.org6.example.com","peer1.org6.example.com","peer2.org6.example.com"],"certificateAuthorities":["ca-org6"],"adminPrivateKey":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org6.example.com/users/Admin@org6.example.com/msp/keystore/b46024bc7e730faa0427dff247474aef72f126fa4937a556bdc2d9c89f85e8fa_sk"},"signedCert":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org6.example.com/users/Admin@org6.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org6.example.com-cert.pem"}}},"orderers":{"orderer.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:7050","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"orderer.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}}},"peers":{"peer0.org1.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:7051","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer0.org1.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer1.org1.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:7056","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer1.org1.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer2.org1.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:7062","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer2.org1.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer2.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer0.org2.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:8051","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer0.org2.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer1.org2.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:8056","eventUrl":"grpcs://localhost:8058","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer1.org2.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer2.org2.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:8062","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer2.org2.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer2.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer0.org3.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:9051","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer0.org3.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer1.org3.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:9056","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer1.org3.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer1.org3.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer2.org3.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:9062","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer2.org3.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer2.org3.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer0.org4.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:10051","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer0.org4.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/peers/peer0.org4.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer1.org4.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:10056","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer1.org4.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/peers/peer1.org4.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer2.org4.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:10062","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer2.org4.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/peers/peer2.org4.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer0.org5.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:11051","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer0.org5.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org5.example.com/peers/peer0.org5.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer1.org5.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:11056","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer1.org5.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org5.example.com/peers/peer1.org5.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer2.org5.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:11062","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer2.org5.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org5.example.com/peers/peer2.org5.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer0.org6.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:12051","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer0.org6.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org6.example.com/peers/peer0.org6.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer1.org6.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:12056","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer1.org6.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org6.example.com/peers/peer1.org6.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}},"peer2.org6.example.com":{"url":"grpcs://localhost:12062","grpcOptions":{"ssl-target-name-override":"peer2.org6.example.com"},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org6.example.com/peers/peer2.org6.example.com/tls/ca.crt"}}},"certificateAuthorities":{"ca-org1":{"url":"https://localhost:7054","httpOptions":{"verify":false},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"},"registrar":[{"enrollId":"admin","enrollSecret":"adminpw"}],"caName":"ca-org1"},"ca-org2":{"url":"https://localhost:8054","httpOptions":{"verify":false},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem"},"registrar":[{"enrollId":"admin","enrollSecret":"adminpw"}],"caName":"ca-org2"},"ca-org3":{"url":"https://localhost:9054","httpOptions":{"verify":false},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/ca/ca.org3.example.com-cert.pem"},"registrar":[{"enrollId":"admin","enrollSecret":"adminpw"}],"caName":"ca-org3"},"ca-org4":{"url":"https://localhost:10054","httpOptions":{"verify":false},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/ca/ca.org4.example.com-cert.pem"},"registrar":[{"enrollId":"admin","enrollSecret":"adminpw"}],"caName":"ca-org4"},"ca-org5":{"url":"https://localhost:11054","httpOptions":{"verify":false},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org5.example.com/ca/ca.org5.example.com-cert.pem"},"registrar":[{"enrollId":"admin","enrollSecret":"adminpw"}],"caName":"ca-org5"},"ca-org6":{"url":"https://localhost:12054","httpOptions":{"verify":false},"tlsCACerts":{"path":"artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org6.example.com/ca/ca.org6.example.com-cert.pem"},"registrar":[{"enrollId":"admin","enrollSecret":"adminpw"}],"caName":"ca-org6"}}}
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.709] [DEBUG] Helper - [NetworkConfig101.js]: constructor, network_config: {"name":"balance-transfer-org3","x-type":"hlfv1","description":"Balance Transfer Network - client definition for org3","version":"1.0","client":{"organization":"org3","credentialStore":{"path":"./fabric-client-kv-org3","cryptoStore":{"path":"/tmp/fabric-client-kv-org3"},"wallet":"wallet-name"}}}
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.709] [DEBUG] Helper - [NetworkConfig101.js]: mergeSettings - additions start
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.709] [DEBUG] Helper - [NetworkConfig101.js]: getOrganization - name org3
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.709] [DEBUG] Helper - [NetworkConfig101.js]: getOrganization - name org3
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.710] [DEBUG] Helper - [FileKeyValueStore.js]: constructor { options: 
   { path: '/home/srihari/hyperledger/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/fabric-client-kv-org3',
     wallet: 'wallet-name',
     cryptoStore: { path: '/tmp/fabric-client-kv-org3' } } }
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.713] [DEBUG] Helper - [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: Hash algorithm: SHA2, hash output size: 256
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.713] [DEBUG] Helper - [utils.CryptoKeyStore]: CryptoKeyStore, constructor - start
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.714] [DEBUG] Helper - [utils.CryptoKeyStore]: constructor, no super class specified, using config: fabric-client/lib/impl/FileKeyValueStore.js
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.714] [DEBUG] Helper - getClientForOrg - ****** END Org3 undefined 


[2019-10-19 13:24:57.714] [DEBUG] Helper - Successfully initialized the credential stores
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.714] [DEBUG] Helper - [FileKeyValueStore.js]: getValue { key: 'Jim' }
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.715] [INFO] Helper - User Jim was not enrolled, so we will need an admin user object to register
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.715] [DEBUG] Helper - [FileKeyValueStore.js]: getValue { key: 'admin' }
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.716] [DEBUG] Helper - [NetworkConfig101.js]: getOrganization - name org3
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.717] [ERROR] Helper - Failed to get registered user: Jim with error: Error: Common connection profile is missing this client's organization and mspid
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.717] [DEBUG] SampleWebApp - -- returned from registering the username Jim for organization Org3
[2019-10-19 13:24:57.717] [DEBUG] SampleWebApp - Failed to register the username Jim for organization Org3 with::failed Error: Common connection profile is missing this client's organization and mspid

I appreciate any help.
````

Comment: Since you changed configuration, you have done some mistakes provide me GitHub link of your changed version I will correct it

Comment: Hi Narendranath,  please find my repository here https://github.com/srihari0033/balance-transfer, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into your repo,

I have found many mistakes

1)  you have defined total 6 organizations in the network-config file, but you have created only 3 files in artifacts folder

2) when you create multiple organization `connection-profile-path` you have to update the same in the mentioned here [file](https://github.com/srihari0033/balance-transfer/blob/master/app/helper.js) it should append orgname dynamically in order to switch b/w orgs

Comment: I made the changes , still i am facing the same issue , I updated the repository also please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `artifacts/network-config.yaml` file, under `organizations:`, you could try to use `org3` instead of `Org3`.

I still can't figure out why `o` is in lower case for `org3` but `O` are in upper case for `Org1` and `Org2`.

It just so happens that it works for me!